# Reference for Plessner's theorem on domains other than the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am currently studying the boundary behavior of analytic functions in bounded domains $G\Subset\Bbb C$ (see this [MathOverflow question and its answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/434932/113756) in order get a clearer picture of the topic).
 While searching for a characterization of boundary points $\zeta_0\in\partial G$ according to the behavior of a given $f:G\to\Bbb C$ as $z\to \zeta_0$, I found [the entry on Plessner's theorem](http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Plessner_theorem) in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics. This theorem classifies boundary points in the unit disk  $\Bbb D$ in Fatou points and Plessner points (see the entry for a quick explanation). In the entry it is said that the theorem can be extended from the unit disk $\Bbb D$ to any domain $G$ with rectifiable boundary and it cites reference [2] for a proof, but this monograph [2] is quite scarce, old and it is also written in German and this motivated my question: do there exists a more modern reference on such matters?

**Refenrences**

[1] E.D. Solomentsev (originator), [Plessner theorem](http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Plessner_theorem). Encyclopedia of Mathematics, ISBN 1402006098.

[2] Ivan Ivanovich Privalov,(A. I. Markushevich, ed.) *Randeigenschaften analytischer Funktionen*. 2 Auflage überarbeitete und ergänzte von A. I. Markushevich Übersetzung aus dem Russischen (German), Hochschulbücher für Mathematik, 25, Berlin: VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften VIII, 247 S. mit 10 Abb. (1956), [MR0083565](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0083565), [Zbl 0073.06501](https://zbmath.org/0073.06501).

Comment: Simply connected domains $G$ with rectifiable boundary are characterized by the property that $f' \in H^1$ for any Riemann map from the unit disc onto $G$ so maybe one can carry the proof in the unit disc case (eg in Collingwood Lohwater Theory of Cluster Sets) directly to $G$; Duren book on $H^p$ spaces has a little in that direction proving Privalov theorem for such

Comment: More precisely Duren proves the $H^p$ analogue version of Privalov (constant non tangential limits on a set of non zero measure implies constant function, where everything is just carried by Riemann maps from the unit disc to $G$) for such $G$ but again I see no reason for the general theorem not to work similarly

Comment: Thank you very much, @Conrad. I suspected that the result implied simply the use of Riemann's mapping theorem but a sentence from the encyclopedic entry made me think there was something finer. (Possibly Solomentsev himself) writes that the definition of Plessner point must be changed: the allowed angles $\Delta$ with vertex $\zeta_0$ should have an amplitude of less than $\pi$ (or $\pm\frac{\pi}{2} $ respect to the normal vector to $\partial G$ through $\zeta_0$) (continues to the next comment...)

Comment: ...(**continues from the previous comment**) your comments, @Conrad, made me think that the requirement is only due to the fact that Privalov applies his extension of the Osgood-Caratheodory theorem, which says that if $\partial G$ is a *rectifiable* Jordan curve then the angles with vertices on it are conserved under conformal mapping (see Kuznetsov, P. I.; Solomentsev, E. D.
"Ivan Ivanovich Privalov (on his ninetieth birthday)" (English) Rus. Math. Surv. 37, No. 4, 153-174 (1982), [Zbl 0511.01016](https://zbmath.org/0511.01016), page 161, theorem 11). (**continues to the next comment**...)

Comment: ...(**continues from the previous comment**) thus $\Delta$ cannot be allowed to have an amplitude larger than or equal to $\pi$ for if otherwise it would necessarily not be preserved when $G$ is mapped on the unit circle.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\Subset$ as opposed to $\subset$?

Comment: @FShrike it means "compactly contained": precisely $G\Subset D$ means that the closure $\overline G$ is contained in $D$.  It's a symbology I first found used by V. S. Vladimirov in his books on PDEs and distribution theory: if $G$ and $D$ are open, this is a compact way to say that while $G\subset D$ their boundaries does not touch.